# Cost for sub collection read in a document Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have structured my data in firestore as:
Collection Reference: "Post"
And each Post has Array of String as Images, Array of String as usersLiked, Caption.

So when I am try to read a Post, and that Particular Post has 3 image strings, and 3 userId's under usersLiked, how many reads do I get for:

- images.length
- usersLiked.length
- checking usersLiked contains the userId of currentUser

Does each string in the sub collections count as one document read?

Thank you all for your help:
I am a beginner and I would appreciate any help with advise on structuring my database efficiently in terms of cost and efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every document you access its content is readable. The sub-collection doesn't matter.

"`Each returned document from your query counts as 1 read.`"

I also recommend checking out here:
1- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing
2- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example